# php session if statement echo

Tags: php, session

I don´t know if this is possible, but im trying to make a session if statement or something, like if the session name is "Simon" it will print a specific text, if the session name is not "Simon" it will do nothing.

This is part of my code and it work:

Part of the user login page:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $row;
```

Part of the page i need the code on, now i just use it to print out the name of the person logged in:

```
   session_start();
   if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
   {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die("Redirecting to index.php");
   }

   echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Are you talking about session `name` or session `value`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){

  if($_SESSION['user']['username'] == "simon"){
   echo "Specific text here";
   }
}
```

For printing the name of the person logged in

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){
    echo "Welcome". $_SESSION['user']['username'];
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome but a better advice is to first Google everything

Answer (score -1):

```
if(S_SESSION['user']=='Simon')
{
     echo "Your text";
}
```

you can type like this

Comment: if it does than, use $row['user'].. instead of simon